# How do I convert and store a 32 bit int value into a 32 length string of its binary pattern?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I have my function set up as:
`int int2bitstr(int I, char *str) {}`

I am trying to take the int I and use loops and bit-level operations to convert that 32 bit int to a 32 length string str that contains its binary pattern of 0's and 1's. The ordering is from most significant bit to least. It needs to be working for signed and unsigned integers. Lastly, I can't use function calls, arithmetic operations other than (++) and (--), and I can't use switch statements. I am honestly lost on where to begin and haven't been able to find anything online so any help in explaining the process in which I will need to go about would be great.

Comment: You forgot to post your attempt at solving this problem.

Comment: I don't want to spoil a solution for you since just solving your assignment won't help you. A hint would be looking at [bitwise arithmetic operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic). I wonder if I can loop over all bits in a number to find out if it is set or not.

Comment: Start by checking whether number is divisible by 2, prepending 1 if it is or 0 if it isn't, then shifting it right by 1 bit.

Comment: What operators *are* you allowed to use?

Comment: Restrictions in what you can use only apply to the *work you submit*. Start by solving the task without those restrictions, and this will give you a feel for it. Then start applying the restrictions.

Comment: Don't describe what you have tried but show it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>

int int2bitstr(int I, char *str)
{
    for(int n=32; n>0; *str++ = "01"[!!(1<<--n&I)]);
    return *str = '\0';
}


int main(void) {
    char str[33];  // Enough space for 32-bits + Terminator
    
    int2bitstr(13421, str);
    
    printf("Answer: %s\n", str);
    return 0;
}
```

## Output:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 5436KB
Answer: 00000000000000000011010001101101
```

### List of Operators used:

- Assignment (`=`)
- Comparison (`>`)
- De-reference (`*`)
- Post-Increment and Pre-Decrement (`++` and `--`)
- String-Quotes (`"`)
- Array operation (`[  ]`)
- Logical Not (`!`)
- Left-Bitshift (`<<`)
- Logical AND (`&`)

I think that is it, and I don't think any of that was banned in your requirements.

Comment: `1<<--n&I` is UB when `n == 32`.  `1u<<--n&I` better.

Comment: `return *str = '\0';` is just weird... What's that supposed to mean?

Comment: The prototype given by OP required an int return value, so I decided to return 0 and terminate the string at the same time.